# Passing server credentials to SSRS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a function in one of my asp projects that hits a server for a report and returns the bytes for it.   I have been using my domain credentials thus far but wish to use instead a sql server authentication on the server itself but I keep getting 401 errors no matter what.

```
public byte[] GetReportBytes(string report, string parameterList)
    {
        string strReportUser = "sqlserveruser";
        string strReportUserPW = "password";
        //not used with sql?
        string strReportUserDomain = "domain";

        string sTargetURL = "reportserver?" +
                            "/folder/" + report + "&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=PDF&" + parameterList;

        HttpWebRequest req =
              (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sTargetURL);
        req.PreAuthenticate = true;
        req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            strReportUser,
            strReportUserPW);

        HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        Stream fStream = HttpWResp.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(fStream);
        return fileBytes;
    }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can authenticate (at least out of the box) to a Reporting Services web url using "sql server authentication".  (Your *data sources* can, but here we are talking about an SSRS web address). "Sql Server Authentication" is not listed as one of the supported methods for [Authentication with the Report Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx)

You possibly could if you wanted to [Configure Custom or Forms Authentication on the Report Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383.aspx)

You can also [Configure Basic Authentication on the Report Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc281309.aspx), but even that doesn't use "sql server authentication" - the request gets passed to the local security authority, which may end up authenticating domain credentials anyway.

In your case, it looks like your web application is essentially acting as a proxy (in a sense) - it is getting the report as a byte array representing a pdf, and returning that, so that the client browser never actually directly communicates with SSRS.

So for that, I would recommend just keeping windows authentication in place, and setting up SSRS permissions such that you delegate to use the identity of your asp.net application pool (and keep that application pool specific to your particular application).  That way, you don't need to store any username or password in your web application code or config.

To accomplish this you will also need to setup your application pool identity user with at least "Content Browser" permissions in SSRS.  Unless your iis instance is on the same machine as your reporting services server, you will need to create a limited permissions domain user, or mirrored local account to set as your application pool identity. (Alternately, if you really want to use the built-in IIS `ApplicationPoolIdentity` user, you can grant SSRS permissions on the machine account (e.g. `<domain>\<machinename>$`) however, that may not be desirable, because it grants much wider access to what services can access SSRS).

If you web application is using forms authentication, then simply doing the following will likely work:

```
 req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

However, if you are using windows authentication for the web site, the above (if memory serves correctly) will instead pass along the identity of the currently logged in windows user, instead of the application pool identity, which may not be what you want.

**Using the SSRS web services**

If you are willing to use the SSRS web service and generate a soap client by using "Add Service Reference" in your project (which your example code doesn't do), you can have the authentication use the application pool identity by doing the following:

```
 var soapClient = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient("ReportExecutionServiceSoap");
 soapClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = 
                            System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

It's been a while since I've done this, but when using the "Service Reference" you'll need to also make sure the WCF bindings are correct.  Below is what I believe worked for me last time:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://theSsrsServer/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" contract="ReportService.ReportExecutionServiceSoap" name="ReportExecutionServiceSoap" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Use windows credential.